# Animate a progress bar during an action with symfony 2 Framework

Tags: ajax, symfony, progress-bar

After several days of research and test, I decided to post this request of information as a last resort :-)

What I'm trying to do is quite simple but despite all the tests I could do ... I can not do it :-(

With the symfony Framework v2.8, I would like to animate a progress bar bootstrap during the execution of an action of a controller and this when the user clicks on a button.

The principle I use is

- updating a SESSION variable during the execution of a processing action
- the reading of this SESSION variable by another action

When the user clicks a button:

- with AJAX I execute my processing action
- with AJAX I execute my action of reading the SESSION variable as long as my treatment action is not completed.

In short, nothing very complicated :-)

The problem I am facing is that my SESSION variable reading action does not execute during the execution of my processing action. Before my action

Treatment yes, after yes, but during ... no!

-> It is impossible for me to read the variable of SESSION during the processing and therefore impossible to animate the progress bar.

Here is the JS code:

```js
$('#generator').click(function() {

    var isInProgress = false;

    traitement();

    function traitement()
    {
        isInProgress = true;
        checkProgress();
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '{{ path('sws_back_createplanning', { 'idChampionnat': Championnat.id })}}',
                async : true,
                cache: false,
                dataType:'html',
                success: function(data){},
                error: function(){  },
                complete: function(){
                    isInProgress = false;
                }
        });
            
    }  

    function checkProgress()
    {
        if( isInProgress != false )
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'championnat/getprogress/',
                async : true,
                cache: false,
                dataType:'html',
                success: function(data){

                     /* animation de la progress bar */

                 },
                error: function(){  },
                complete: function(){
                    checkProgress();
                }
            });
        } else { }
    }
})
```

Here is the processing action code:

```html
public function traitementAction($id){

 
 $session = new Session();
 $session->set('progress', 0);

 // traitement #1

 $session->set('progress', 25);

 // traitement #2

 $session->set('progress', 50);

 // traitement #3

 $session->set('progress', 75);

 // traitement #4

 $session->set('progress', 100); 

 return new Response ("Traitement terminé");

}
```

Here is the code of the reading action of the SESSION variable:

```html
public function getProgressAction(Request $request)
{

 $percent = $this->get('session')->get('progress');
       
 if ($percent == 100){
  $session = new Session();
  $session->remove('progress');        
 }
    
 return new Response($percent);  
}
```

In my tests, I also converted my action to "command" and executed this "command" with the Process component.

- with the RUN () method, the same behavior as with my controller action is detected
- with the START (asynchronous execution) method, execution of the "command" is stopped at the end of the action of the controller which executes the "command" -> due to the concept of process

Parent / child. This means, if I understood correctly, that as soon as the parent process (execution of the controller action) ends, this ends the child process that started the process

"COMMAND" -> a child process does not survive its parent process.

Here is the code of the controller action that starts the "COMMAND":

```html
public function commandAction($id)
{
    $commandline = "php console app:generate-planning ".$idChampionnat;
    $process = new Process($commandline);
    $dossier = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $process->setWorkingDirectory($dossier);

    $process->start();   // https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20513
    $process->wait();    // Pour ne pas que l'exécution de la commande ne soit 'Killée' ... mais empêche la lecture de la variable de SESSION tant que la commande n'est pas terminée
      
    return new Response ("Commande démarrée");
}
```

So to summarize my problem, I can not execute my two queries at the same time. I certainly have to miss something ... can you help me?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ... the problem was with the session management (close session).

-> https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/plusieurs-requetes-ajax-en-meme-temps